# Mongoid::Criteria#last modifies the criteria and gives wrong results

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid3

This is an interesting pattern I found using mongoid (3.0.0), which I suspect is a bug.

```
1.9.3p194 :007 > products = Product.order_by([:_id, :asc ]).limit(5)
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
   selector: {},
   options:  {:sort=>{"_id"=>1}, :limit=>5},
   class:    Product,
   embedded: false>

1.9.3p194 :008 > products.map(&:_id)
 => ["500fa5614f6d3a23d0000002", "500fa5614f6d3a23d0000003", "500fa5614f6d3a23d0000004", "500fa5614f6d3a23d0000005", "500fa5614f6d3a23d0000006"]
```

So far so good! However, if I issue the following - I get weird results.

```
1.9.3p194 :012 > products.count
 => 3654017
```

This shows me **all** the product count instead of 5 (since i have :limit => 5)

```
1.9.3p194 :012 > Product.count
 => 3654017
```

Now the even more weird part:

```
1.9.3p194 :010 > products.last
 => #<Product _id: 504952620a5e2323460000aa, _type: nil, ... >
```

This should have been _id: 500fa5614f6d3a23d0000006. Now, if I try to map the ids again, I get:

```
1.9.3p194 :019 > products.map(&:id)
 => ["504952620a5e2323460000aa", "504952620a5e2323460000a9", "504952620a5e2323460000a8", "5049524f0a5e2323460000a7", "504950ab0a5e2323460000a6"]
```

This has changed the criteria entirely! However, I get proper results with this:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > products = Product.order_by([:_id, :asc ]).limit(5)
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {},
  options:  {:sort=>{"_id"=>1}, :limit=>5},
  class:    Product,
  embedded: false>

1.9.3p194 :028 > products[0].id
 => "500fa5614f6d3a23d0000002" 
1.9.3p194 :029 > products[-1].id
 => "500fa5614f6d3a23d0000006"
```

This does seem to be related to Mongoid 3.0.0 though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First keep in Mind that Mongoid has a lazy loading functionnality: the query will be trigerred at the last moment possible.

Let's dig your issues:

- `last`: it sets `limit` to `-1` so it will override your previous setting. To get your expected behavior, you must oblige Mongoid to make the query using `to_a`: `products = Product.order_by([:_id, :asc ]).limit(5).to_a.last`
- `count`: if you want to respect the `limit`, use `count(true)`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. The count(true) does not work though. `p.count(true)` throws a `NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for true:TrueClass  from (mongoid-3.0.3)/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:70:in count`